# git: Merge newer branch into older branch without picking trunk chnages

Tags: git

I have a situation where code developed in a branch off master (FEATURE) needs to be merged into an older branch RELEASE (and then released as part of a release from that older branch).

```
1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8->(master)
     \     \
     \     \-X-Y-Z->(FEATURE)
     \
     \-A-B->(RELEASE)
```

If I simply say `git merge FEATURE` on the RELEASE branch, I'll pick up commits 4,5,6 - and I don't want them.

I'd rather not do cherry-picking as the FEATURE has 80+ commits, each potentially conflict-prone.

Is there a way to just merge X,Y,Z into RELEASE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new branch `feature_to_be_merged` based on `feature`. Rebase it on commit 3 and merge it onto `release`.

Beware that the rebase operation might lead to conflicts.

Comment: Rebase is as bad as cherry-picking WRT conflicts... But- that may be my only option.

Comment: @Arkadiy Well there is no secret since `feature` started later then `release`